Batch File return values from function call returning blanks - split a csv string and return parts
Why no results returned in my batch file code for server and database variables?
Batch code:
cls
@echo off
call :split2 "MyServer,MyDatabase" server database

echo server=%server%, database=%database%
goto End
:split2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=%~1
echo x=%x%
set /a i=0
for %%b in ("%x:,=" "%") do (
    set array[!i!]=%%~b
    set /a i+=1
)
endlocal
setlocal enableextensions
set %2=%array[0]%
echo server=%2
set %3=%array[1]%
echo database=%3
endlocal
goto :eof
:End

Results:
x=MyServer,MyDatabase
server=server
database=database
server= , database=

Shouldn't be blank, I have tried all sorts of setlocal options nothing seems to work.

I see now when you call setlocal ... I think it ends when you complete the function whether you have endlocal or not but use setlocal outside the function so in the main body it works

You are not using setlocal or endlocal correctly.

Consider this distilled version of your script.
@echo off
call :split2 "MyServer,MyDatabase" server database

echo server=%server%, database=%database%
exit /b

:split2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=%~1
set /a i=0
for %%b in ("%x:,=" "%") do (
    set array[!i!]=%%~b
    set /a i+=1
)
endlocal & (set "%2=%array[0]%") & (set "%3=%array[1]%")
exit /b

Other than stripping out all the debug code, the chief difference is that the endlocal is evaluated and parsed at the same time that you set the (output) variables.
endlocal & (set "%2=%array[0]%") & (set "%3=%array[1]%")

Setting the variables inside the setlocal/endlocal block will be ineffectual when you return from the split2 subroutine. You have to do the setting outside.
There are probably other ways to accomplish it, but in this example, it is accomplished because the variable substitution is made when the line is parsed, but the assignment happens after the parsing is complete and endlocal has been executed.
